# Override ToString() implementation of anonymous objects

Tags: c#

```
        var sample = new
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now,
            Name = "Hello"
        };
        Trace.TraceInformation("{0}", sample);
```

outputs as

> ProcessInvocation86.exe Information: 0 : { Time = 04.11.2012 22:07:52,
>   Name = Hello }

I'd like different formatting in my application. Is there a way to change the implementation of ToString() for anonymous objects in C#? Maybe some static field per `AppDomain` or something?

Comment: Probably not for anonymous types.  When you start moving from a simple data structure to a slightly richer object which exposes functionality (such as overriding a method), you'll need to define an explicit type.

Comment: I managed to do this: `var sample = new { Time = DateTime.Now, Name = "Hello", ToString = new Func<string>(() => { return"xxx"; })};Console.WriteLine("{0}", sample.ToString());`. Unfortunatelly it seems there is no way to access `this` from ToString Func, so it can return only constants or global variables - useless I guess :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't do this - `ToString`, `Equals`, and `GetHashCode` have default implementation provided by framework. To override this functionality you should inherit from your anonymous type, which is impossible.

Use `String.Format` to get desired output.

Comment: I'll add that if you need this kind of functionality, then you should define a real class and extend it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

As far as im aware, there is no way to override the default `ToString` behaviour.
Might be worthwhile looking at some of the posts from  Eric Lippert about anonymous types: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/anonymous+types/

Probably best to create a simple class for this purpose:

e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public DateTime Time { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format("Time = {0}. Name = {1}.", Time, Name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know, some guys will actually punch me for such a solution and I agree, that you shouldn't use it in production. If you have specific functionality for some bunch of data - this should definitely go to separate class. But for minor issues, you can use a little of reflection like this to write some custom formatter (I repeat, I'm not suggesting to use it in production  ):

```
private string FormatProperties<T> (T obj)
{
    string result = "";
    var type = typeof(T);
    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
    {
        result += string.Format("{0}:{1}\r\n", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then the call

```
var anon = new {Name = "Ilya", Surname = "Ivanov"};
Console.WriteLine (FormatProperties(anon));
```

Will result in printed

```
Name:Ilya
Surname:Ivanov
```

And then you can cache types for performance benefits and get into another types of troubles.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't exactly ideal.. but you could create an extension method that takes a function that does the formatting.

Following example formatted for LinqPad
**EXAMPLE**

```
void Main()
{
var sample = new
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now,
            Name = "Hello",
        };

    sample.ToAnonString(()=>sample.Name).Dump();

}
public static class ovs{
       public static string ToAnonString(this object o,Func<string> exp){
         return exp();
       }
    }
```